# How to tackle an error : Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, build

Launching lib\main.dart on M2006C3MII in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: **Build failed with an exception.**

- Where:
  Build file **'C:\Users\Rana\Desktop\Flutter Projects\new_soft\android\build.gradle' line: 26**
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Rana\Desktop\Flutter Projects\new_soft\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Rana.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\52edrvulxtnk4ivgfae602cyx).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1